# Turn the Tooltip Bootstrap functionality off

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, jquery-events

According the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) is is possible to turn off the functionality just doing `$('body').off('.alert.data-api')`.
In the case of [tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) I tried the following from js console `$('body').off('.tooltip.data-api')` but it does not disable the tooltip on bottons.
Any hints how to precede?

Comment: try excluding the "bootstrap-tooltip.js" file from your page. Also, since it doesnt do what the documentation says it should, raise an issue here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/new

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can't disable tooltips that way because it has no event listener on the body. Instead, you can disable the tooltips themselves using the code below.

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip()          // Init tooltips
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('disable') // Disable tooltips
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('enable')  // (Re-)enable tooltips
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('destroy') // Hide and destroy tooltips
```

---

**Edit:** For Bootstrap 4, the `'destroy'` command has been replaced by the [`'dispose'` command](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#tooltipdispose), so:

```js
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('dispose') // Hide and destroy tooltips in Bootstrap 4
```

Comment: How can I disable the tooltip for a single element and at the same time enable the default browser hover tooltip?

Comment: `$('#my-element').tooltip('disable').attr('title', $('#my-element').attr('data-original-title'));`

Comment: Jasny, is there also a way to do the same for a group of thumbnail elements? I have tried replacing #my-element with .my-class but this obviously does not work; it applies the first title of the group to all elements in the group.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response! I found I could ask fancybox API to use a different attribute... that way I get tooltip on thumbnail + caption on expanded image: http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/

Comment: @MikeFlynn, you are probably using the wrong selector. Please look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220597/destroy-all-bootstrap-tooltips-in-a-div/28220763#28220763

Comment: This is great. Why isn't this documented on the Bootstrap site?

Comment: for Bootstrap 4, use tooltip('dispose') instead of tooltip('destroy')

Answer (score 9):

Can you try:

```
$('a[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
$('a[rel=tooltip]').off('.tooltip');
```

Don't forget to change the selector. Works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/D9JTZ/

Comment: Don't unbind the event. The Tooltip object still exists, which makes it impossible to re-enable the tooltip. You need to either disable it or destroy it completely.

Comment: Note that you need to precede that line with $('a[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();

Answer (score 4):

To **permanently** disable a tooltip:

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("disable");`

To stop the tooltip from being displayed on hover but have the ability to re-enable it:

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("destroy");`

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); // re-enabling`

Comment: This did what I wanted (replacing `destroy` with `dispose` for bootstrap 4). I was hiding/showing parent elements based on a child element which had a tooltip, so the tooltip would end up still being visible, even if the parent element was hidden. calling `tooltip('dispose')` and then `.tooltip({placement: "top"})` right after fixed the broken on-hover, but made sure that the tooltip was still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using CSS! Just add `.tooltip { visibility: hidden }` to your CSS file.

If you want to make your link accessibility friendly without the tooltip, then just add `aria-label= "Here's a link description."`

Hope this helps!

Comment: this will also hide the text of the `<div>`, and may not be what you are looking for

Comment: It worked for me. @JeffXiao Why should it hide the text of the div?

Answer (score -3):

I struggled too with this, but I came up with a solution!
In my case I use Jquery Sortable which is ofcourse annoying when you have tooltips flying around!

So I made a variable

```
var sort = '0`;
```

And since almost every tooltip has an init() function, I created

```
if(window.sort!='1') { // So I'm not sorting
  init.tooltip();
}
```

So, this can be the easiest enable/disable function!