# jQuery Bootstrap Tooltip - 2 tooltips shown on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

On mouse over I have 2 tooltips displayed (on 1st mouseover only the top one is shown, on any following mouseover 2 tooltips are shown - see picture):

```
$('.pic').on('mouseover touchstart', '.pin', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('title', pin.text()).tooltip();
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$('.pic').on('mouseout', '.pin', function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

[SOLVED]

```
$(this).tooltip('destroy');
```

did the trick!

Comment: where is the picture?

Comment: can't attach it, the site hangs for a minute every time I try to attach it

Comment: It's because you're creating another tooltip within the `mouseover touchstart` event handler.

Comment: this site won't upload the picture. well, it's basically a tooltip on top of the .pin and another box to the right of it. I've changed mouseover for mouseenter and it still shows 2 tooltips

Comment: If it is necessary to create the tooltip on mouseover... You should "dispose" (destroy) it on mouseout. See this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220763/2159528).

Comment: I guess the problem was Concrete5 uses Bootstrap3 while I was trying to dispose it which is from Bootstrap4. As soon as I changed the 'hide' for 'destroy', it got fixed and only shows a single tooltip. It works with 'mouseover'. Thank you!

Comment: Why wouldn't the site upload pictures?